# Should we burninate [mtg-history]?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Our site has these two tags:

- [history](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) on 42 questions. The tag wiki says: “The history tag explores variation editions of changes to a board game. It also is used for looking into the past events that lead up to a game in some way.”
- [mtg-history](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-history) on 6 questions. No tag wiki. Two of these questions are also tagged [history]. All questions are questions about the history of MTG. (The tag is not about [the Historic mechanic](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3Ahistoric&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name).)

I believe the [mtg-history] tag is redundant since we can already signify we're asking about MTG history with a combination of the tags [magic-the-gathering] [history]. That's what other games are already doing: [yu-gi-oh] [history], [go] [history], [poker] [history], etc.

Should we burninate [mtg-history](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-history)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, let's burninate it. It's redundant, and we can & should tag MTG history questions as [magic-the-gathering](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering) [history](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history).

Answer (score 2):

I've just today burninated [mtg-history](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-history), since it seems like we didn't actually do that back in 2019. At the time of writing the post in favor of burninating the tag is at +17/–0.

I've removed it from the following questions which are all tagged [magic-the-gathering](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering) [history](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history):

- [Has the significance of the term 'cast' changed?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7056/has-the-significance-of-the-term-cast-changed)
- [Can anyone provide a citation for the existence of pre-alpha MTG rules about an initiative stat in combat?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/48870/can-anyone-provide-a-citation-for-the-existence-of-pre-alpha-mtg-rules-about-an)
- [What's the "biggest change we've ever made" in Magic?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/39885/whats-the-biggest-change-weve-ever-made-in-magic)
- [What land destruction enabler was wrongfully banned in the early history of Magic: the Gathering?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/39859/what-land-destruction-enabler-was-wrongfully-banned-in-the-early-history-of-magi)
- [What exactly was so broken about Urza's Block?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/9576/what-exactly-was-so-broken-about-urzas-block)
- [When did big creatures in Magic stopped having a mantainance cost?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6162/when-did-big-creatures-in-magic-stopped-having-a-mantainance-cost)
- [Is "The Aristocrats" the first WBR deck to top 8 a Pro Tour?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/11142/is-the-aristocrats-the-first-wbr-deck-to-top-8-a-pro-tour)
- [Where did Interrupts in Alpha & Beta Magic Editions end?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/56186/where-did-interrupts-in-alpha-beta-magic-editions-end)
- [How would casting a Lightning Bolt in response to Giant Growth work in early Magic?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/56166/how-would-casting-a-lightning-bolt-in-response-to-giant-growth-work-in-early-mag)

Comment: Strangely enough now that the related tag is gone, a user has started asking questions about historic rules versions and mechanics, like the retired card type interrupt.